# Install AWS SSL Certificate to home server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, flask, https, ssl-certificate

I have a domain name bought from AWS, and can get SSl certificate from AWS ACM.
I could install the certificates to Load Balancer for EC2.
Now I am hosting a server at home, either a NodeJS app or Python Flask app.
How can I get the website to use https protocol?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the website to use https protocol?

Yes, you can, but not from AWS ACM. The SSL certificates from [ACM can only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html) be used on:

- Elastic Load Balancing
- Amazon CloudFront
- Amazon API Gateway

For home server, you have to get a SSL certificate from a third party. A popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/ which offers free public SSL certificates. But to register an SSL cert, you will need a DNS domain for your home server.